# What is the difference between passing session in updateOne option vs passing session in bulkWrite option in mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to understand the bulkWrite operation of mongoose where I encountered a situation where I have to either process all transactions of 4 different collection or none.
Below are the 2 codes and I don't understand that how they are different

```
const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
sess.startTransaction();
for (let data of lotOfData) {
    bulkUpdateArr.push({
        updateOne: {
            "filter": { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data._id) },
            "update": {
                $set: data,
            },
            "options": {
                "upsert": true,
                "new": true,
                "session":sess
            }
        }
    })
}
await Products.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateArr,{"ordered":false});
```

The other code is

```
const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
sess.startTransaction();
for (let data of lotOfData) {
    bulkUpdateArr.push({
        updateOne: {
            "filter": { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data._id) },
            "update": {
                $set: data,
            },
            "options": {
                "upsert": true,
                "new": true,
            }
        }
    })
}
await Products.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateArr,{"ordered":false,"session":sess});
```

As you can see that in first code I am explicitly providing session to all updateOne and in second code I am just providing it to bulkWrite Option.
Are both of them correct?
If yes then what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this code example](https://gist.github.com/alexbjorlig/890ff51184cf98961f3251c0c2af378f) I would surmise that there is no real difference in your case. The second code snippet you provide seems like less code.
The first to me seems like it would be the same as doing something like this:

```js
const session = client.startSession();
session.startTransaction();
try {
        await db
            .collection('Account')
            .findOneAndUpdate({ name: 'A' }, { $set: { balance: 6 } }, { session });
         await db
            .collection('Account')
            .findOneAndUpdate({ name: 'B' }, { $set: { balance: 6 } }, { session });
        await db
            .collection('Account')
            .findOneAndUpdate({ name: 'B' }, { balance: 7 }, { session });
        await session.commitTransaction();
} catch (error) {
       ...
} finally {
        session.endSession();
}
```

further clarification of transactions can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/), and also take a look at the [bulk write docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/).

Pay close attention to multi-document transactions. Hope this helps. Happy coding!